# Addressable ICs similar to WS2811 for monochrome LED

Tags: led, serial, communication, rgb, ws2811

For my home decoration, i want to individually address the led strings . Since one string is of a single color, i need an ic with **serial communication** similar to **WS2811** ic **but monochrome** to control them.

I'll use a mosfet or whatever required driven by that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS2811 strings were in the past available in single colour; they had 3 LEDs per chip.  If you're building your own strip, that's still an option.

So the first LED is on the red channel second on green and and the third on blue, fourth LED is on the red of the second chip then green and blue, next chip, etc.

Comment: The decoder chip has no idea what the colors are.  In an RGB strip there's a repeating pattern of three the programmer has to match when working in terms of raw channels, in a monochrome strip they're all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your LEDs are spatially distributed, there's also shift registers with LED driving inputs, meant exactly for such applications.

Look through the "power management"->"LED drivers" categories on sites like ti.com.

Comment: Shift registers wont work in my case. My led string lights are seperated  almost1.5 -2 feet apart and all across the perimeter of my roof and boundary,  thats very long (atleast 230 meters of length

Comment: uhhhh are you sure a WS2811-style controller then suffices? You need *some* signal quality between LEDs.

Comment: Not sure,  but signals are sort of reconstruted while passing over ic,  so if every ic is capable of sending signal over 2 feet distance,  that'll work.

Comment: Also i couldn't find any usefull ic supporting serial data transmission like ws2911 in the 'power management' section of ti.com

Comment: I specifically said in the LED drivers section of that, look for things that work as shift registers. It's not hard to use that website, but here you go: https://www.ti.com/power-management/led-drivers/overview.html

Comment: For your convenience: this: https://www.ti.com/product/TLC6C5912?qgpn=tlc6c5912

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.  This is a good , but it won't fulfill my purpose,  instead uts making it worse.  For time being,  I'll stick with ws2811, using only one channel and leaving other two color channels empty

Comment: @AmanKumar you started from the right idea but then went wrong.  Use the WS2812, but  put the same color LED on each channel rather than skipping them.  It's all the same to the chip.  You'd only need to skip if you bought manufactured RGB strips and wanted to use them as red, green, or blue monochrome...

Comment: @chrisStratton  the idea is to keep wire clutter as low as possible.  I realised that the ws2811 is still cheap enough.  By placing one ic per string,  I'll only have to run 3 wired in parallel.

Comment: but what's the advantage of that? "by using three times as many wires as necessary, I'm reducing wire clutter" doesn't sound overly sensible.

Comment: You need power and ground as well as signal.  But it seems there's more being misunderstood.  A monochrome string isn't logically any different than a color one, you just wouldn't unify the pixels of an IC in one place.  Typically they're a flex circuit with cut / patch points after each three or some other repeating group using a single IC.